# What additional costs can I expect when visiting a restaurant in the US where service is included?

Tags: usa, new-york-city, restaurants, tipping, taxes

I am going to a Michelin three-star restaurant in New York City this fall. On their website, it says that for the fixed-price tasting menu, both the course menu and the beverage pairing are ”inclusive of service”.

Does that mean that if add those two prices together, that's what it ultimately will cost me? Am I not expected to tip a single penny, even if the service was fantastic? Will there be sales and/or state tax added on top of that?

For the record, even though I come from Europe, I have absolutely no problem with tipping when I am expected to. I probably over-tip anyway when I'm the US, just to not cheat the service staff over their hard-earned wages. I don't want to offend anyone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80749/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-what-additional-costs-can-i-expect-when-visitin).

Comment: Did you ever have your meal? Love to hear if you ended up leaving an additional tip or not.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Yes I did go and I ended up not tipping. The waitress told us several times that it was included and there wasn't even a tip line on the credit card slip. I guess she wouldn't have mind if I would have left her a small tip as a token of appreciation, but it really didn't feel necessary. During dinner, I was watching to see if other patrons were tipping and they weren't, except for one (didn't see how much it was), so I kind of went with the flow.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

"Inclusive of service" should mean that you are not expected to tip. That doesn't mean that you can't tip if you want to, especially if the service was good. The US restaurant business is pretty much wedded to tips, and they will be appreciated no matter what. However a Michelin 3-star restaurant *should* be paying its wait staff a decent wage, with or without tips.

Yes, there will be sales tax on top of the price (unless you are in a state where there is no sales tax).

Comment: Are there any states which include Sales Tax in the price (the European model)?

Comment: To answer a couple of mentioned questions: the only US states without sales tax are Delaware, Montana, Oregon, and New Hampshire. Alaska doesn't have a *state* sales tax, but local municipalities are allowed to charge a local sales tax. I'm not aware of anywhere in the US where taxes are routinely included in the cost listed on the menu or price sticker, with the possible exception of ballpark concession stands or similar venues like carnivals and/or amusement parks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80748/discussion-on-answer-by-djclayworth-additional-costs-for-restaurant-visit-in-the).

Comment: @BradC New Hampshire does not have a general sales tax, but it _does_ have a sales tax on hotels and restaurants.

Comment: @NigelTouch Such a thing is exceptionally rare; gasoline is the only common product which is all-inclusive. There are tens of thousands of juridictions in the U.S. with sales tax authority, so as consumers we've grown accustomed to wanting to know the "base price" and then venue-shopping, knowing a certain product is taxed a little more or a little less in an adjacent town or county, or sometimes just outside of a certain district within a city, or at certain times of the year (many places have sales tax holidays this time of year for school supplies, for example).

Comment: A chat room was created for this discussion. Link above.

Comment: @BradC in my experience drink prices, etc. at bars are posted with tax included, occasionally rounded by a penny or two.  And plenty of individual stores, etc. do so as well

Answer (score 28):

I dined at Per Se last night, so I guess there's a 20% chance that you'll be dining there as well (there are only 5 three-star's in New York as of 2018).

When the bill came, it was very clear that gratuity was already included. I even received a beautifully hand-written bill with no spot for additional gratuity. The staff were excellent and I have no doubt that it would not be held against you if you did not include an additional tip. Especially as your bill can *easily* reach $1,000 for two people without even buying wine. And if I were dining for something that was *not* a special occasion, I would probably have left it at that.

However on our occasion (10 year wedding anniversary and my wife's birthday) they really went the extra mile. We received personal touches and a note from the sous-chef, complimentary champagne, and they sent an additional goodie bag home for our kids. And because we're not big drinkers, we we went with non-alcoholic beverages *which they did not charge us for* and the bar tender saw to us personally and honestly stole the show with his non-alcoholic cocktails.

With these extra above-and-beyond touches, we did leave an additional 10% tip on top of the already-included gratiuity - mostly because of the bar tender.

Comment: Man, I wish I could select both as answers; @DJClayworth for promptness and yours for empirically sharing your experience from last night...

Comment: @Daniel take DJClayworth's - his is more thorough and broad. Also the going salary for a 3-star restaurant server can be close to or at 6 figures for the best of the best, so it's not the same situation as a small diner or hole-in-the-wall place.

Comment: "$1,000 for two people without even buying wine"!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @camden_kid yes. But it's not a surprise, you know this going in.

Comment: @MarkHenderson still, this is a lot. The one-star Trianon restaurant next to me in Versailles (a Ramsey restaurant), right at the entrance to the Versailles gardens and the Trianon Hotel is 200 EUR/person for the sampling menu (or whatever it is called in English - a showcase menu or something where they put seven servings of good stuff). When biking with my kids we routinely stop in front of it and discuss whether  we should hop in for a lunch or eat at home :). EDIT: what I meant by this comment is that I find the prices high compared to a posh place in France

Comment: @WoJ no argument here. I'm not condoning the price, but paying way too much is sort of the point at some places. It's like flexing your muscles. Your muscle that's used for spending too much money.

Comment: @MarkHenderson: I did an edit to my comment right after posting it because I wanted to make it clear that I do not criticize the price. Everyone is free to do what they want with their money and this is great. The comment was rather directed at *But it's not a surprise, you know this going in* and I just wanted to highlight that a similar restaurant in Versailles is much less and that i am surprised by the difference. Out of curiosity I had a look at the *Le Meurice* which is one of the most expensive restaurants in paris (if not the one). The most expensive menu is at 450 EUR (530 USD)